# Spin half for the value of $|1 0\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, normalization

Spin-1/2
The eigenspinor , $X=aX_++bX_-$
$$X_+=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 1\\
0\end{array} \right) $$$$X_-=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 0\\
1\end{array} \right)$$
They are define like this because they work well in the following?
$S_zX_+={\hbar}/2X_+$ and $S^2X_+={\frac{3}{4}}{\hbar}X_+$.

But for $|s m \rangle$, I don't understand why do we need to put $|1 0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}  | \uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow \uparrow\rangle$
Because without $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ we can prove the eigenvalue of $S^2$ is 2har.
Why $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$?

Answer (score 2):

That $1/\sqrt{2}$ factor is for the normalization.
i.e. to ensure that $\langle 1 0 | 1 0\rangle = 1$ where $\langle 1 0 |$ is the conjugate transpose of $|1 0\rangle$

Comment: Thanks. so easy,no wonder my book didn't explain.

<10|10>=1

<10|10>=$A^2(\uparrow\downarrow + \downarrow\uparrow)(\uparrow\downarrow + \downarrow\uparrow)$

$A^2(\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow+\uparrow\downarrow  \downarrow\uparrow+\downarrow\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow+ \downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow)=1$ The arrow can be expand like this?

Then use $\downarrow\uparrow$=o,$\downarrow\downarrow=1$

$A^2=0+1+1+0$